# Calling .net 1.1 from Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I am trying to reference a .net 1.1 assembly from Powershell. I believe I have tried both 1.0 and 2.0 and I have tried on Win XP and Win 7 64 bit.

```
add-type -path "path-to-dll"
```

I then get back the following error:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve
the LoaderExceptions property for more information. At line:1 char:9
+ add-type <<<<  -path "C:\Program Files\Propel Systems\Cimera eval\cimera common.dll"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

I have scoured Google as to whether Powershell supports 1.1 or not but cannot find an answer. Does it?

Secondly the message says "Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property..". But I can find absolutely no reference ANYWHERE as to HOW.

Comment: Have you tried `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Your.dll")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) method.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Your_DotNet_1.1.dll")
```

Just making my comment an answer since it works.

Comment: NB: I had the same issue, but sadly this fix didn't work for me.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692261/loading-a-specific-dll-in-powershell for more info.